# What is the correct way to save connection settings/connect to a mysql database in the Slim framework?

Tags: php, slim

I'm really liking the Slim framework but can't seem find documentation on database settings or where to put that kind of information.  I tried doing it inline, but that was out of scope for requests.  What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Personally I include the settings in an `require_once` file at the top of each page

Comment: @Vector what does your settings page look like?  When I made the connection outside of the $app->*, there was a scoping issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most common use with Slim is to include a 3rd party ORM or a similar approach.
Have you tried one like [PHP RedBean](http://www.redbeanphp.com/)?